# setInterval function works only once

Tags: javascript

I want to use setInterval function for a repeated task. Here is my autoUpdate function which works one time.

```
var intervalId;

function autoUpdate() {
    intervalId = setInterval(updateFile(fileId, 'root', document.getElementById('editor').value), 10000);
}
```

Here is my stopAutoUpdate function.

```
function stopAutoUpdate() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

What is wrong with this code? Thanx.

Edit= I have the title edited. Sorry.

Comment: "which works one time" — Do you mean that it only runs once? So it is `setInterval` that doesn't work? not `clearInterval`?

Comment: The title is a red herring, the duplicate is correct.

Comment: @Atti Don't Execute Function - See Here -> https://jsfiddle.net/myt05mad/

Comment: @Quentin i have edited the ttitle. Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the interval function correctly:

```
function autoUpdate() {
    intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        updateFile(fileId, 'root', document.getElementById('editor').value)
    }, 10000);
}
```

What you are doing is actually calling the function once instead of passing it.
The clearInterval itself looks correct.

Comment: To clarify what @Lain is saying, you're calling the updateFile function instead of setting it as what should be run on each interval. edit: he cleared it up himself afterwards so ignore me :)

Comment: @Lain Man isn't neutral.

Comment: @Mike C: Historically seen, it is/was and could be. A person used to be a man.. which a man can still see in expressions like 'mankind'.

Comment: @Lain im definitely a man, but i didnt wrestled a bear, at least until now. Thanx for the answer.

Comment: @Mike C: http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/08/the-word-man-was-originally-gender-neutral/

Comment: @Atti: A man is welcome :)

Comment: @Lain Sure, but I think you'd be hard pressed to get anyone to believe that the standard usage of it doesn't refer to a male. What it meant historically doesn't really matter now.

Comment: Mike C: Certainly. It is more of a fun thing from GoT. I did not think of it to be confusing/offending.

Comment: @Lain No worries. This line "[a] man can actually be neutral, whereas woman cant" made me think it was a misogyny thing instead of a GoT thing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `setInterval` param you set, it receives a `function definition`, but your giving the result of a `function execution`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with `clearInterval`. You're using `setInterval` wrong and may not have the ID in scope. Here's a simplified example of how it should work.

```js
// Make sure the ID is declared somewhere that both functions
// can access it
var intervalID;
var calls = 0;

function displayStuff(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
  calls++;
  
  if (calls >= 10) {
    stopAutoUpdate(); 
  }
}

function autoUpdate() {
  intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    // Notice how I'm wrapping the call in an anonymous function
    // without this, it will just call the function once, not repeat it
    displayStuff('Auto:', intervalID, calls);
  }, 800);
}

function stopAutoUpdate() {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
  console.log('Done');
}

// Start the interval
autoUpdate();
```